# Como hacer mandar a llamar un reporte con iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

Hola he creado un reporte con ireport y jsperReport y he utilizado este codigo:

```
String path = "C:\\Users\\Juan\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Archivero\\src\\Reportes\\Pendientes.jrxml";
try {
    JasperReport reporte;
    reporte=(JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObjectFromLocation(path);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint;
    jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(path,null,con.ConBD);
    JasperViewer viewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint,false);
    viewer.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    viewer.setVisible(true);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

La clase de conexión es la siguiente:

```
package Clases;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Conexion {

    public Connection ConBD;
    public Statement SentenciaSQL;
    public ResultSet Consulta;
    String url = "src\\BaseDatos\\doc_sal.db";
    public void Abrir() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            ConBD = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + url);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos\n" + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            ConBD.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Actualmente no funciona y me gustaría que me ayuden a resolverlo o en que me falla.
Posdata creo que es esta linea de codigo:

```
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(path,null,con.ConBD);
```

ya que en la documentacion que lo encontre en lugar de usar `con.ConBD` solo usaba `con.Abrir()`.

Comment: Sé más específico, ¿Qué error te da?

Comment: No simplemente no hace nada